# Can GNU `ls` color files using arbitrary filename patterns

Tags: ls

Is there a way to specify a rule that might color every file whose name is exactly `MAKEFILE` red? Or perhaps any file containing the substring `make` (of any case) red?

As far as I can tell, you can only specify extensions.

Comment: You could use `*MAKEFILE`, but then `FOOMAKEFILE` will also get coloured.

Answer (score 2):

I have not read the manual, or looked at the source code, but I think you can sort of do it.

It seems, from my experiments, that the `LS_COLOR` pattern, for file-names, must start with a `*`. From looking at the examples it seems that this is how the grammar is made un-ambiguous. e.g. `di=…` is for directories, and `*di=…` means it ends with `di`. The dot however does not seem to be special.

Therefore you can colour any file ending with MAKEFILE, e.g. `LS_COLOR=':*MAKEFILE=01;35:'`. That is it only works for file-name endings, but nothing to do with dots (extension).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say no. You can see all of the colors for ls in the `LS_COLORS` variable in your shell.

Here's what mine looked like:

```
$ echo $LS_COLORS
rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
```

If you try appending `MAKEFILE=01;31:` to mimic the red that appears for **tar.gz** files to the end of the environment variable it ends up just disabling all of the colors.

It appears to only accept types and extensions. By types I mean what appears towards the beginning of the variable like **fi** being for a normal file and 
**di** for directory and so on.

Here are the various colors sourced from here(http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html):

```
Black       0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
Blue        0;34     Light Blue    1;34
Green       0;32     Light Green   1;32
Cyan        0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
Red         0;31     Light Red     1;31
Purple      0;35     Light Purple  1;35
Brown       0;33     Yellow        1;33
Light Gray  0;37     White         1;37
```

Comment: I did some experiments based on this answer, it is not quite correct, so I created a new answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532926/4778 (in essence there is nothing special about dots, so you can do any ends with pattern).